# Aframe + Meteor - Add a conditional custom component to an entity

Tags: meteor, aframe

```
<a-gltf-model id='playerone' {{#if myplayer playerone}}entitymove{{/if}} src="#myMixBun"> </a-gltf-model>
```

Using Aframe in Meteor, I want to add the custom component “entitymove” if the value of myplayer is “playerone”.

The value of `{{myplayer}}` is `“playerone”` in `main.html`, so the variable is set correctly. But I get the Meteor error `“A template tag of type BLOCKOPEN is not allowed here”`.

If “entitymove” was a “class”, for instance,  I think I could solve this with the following:

```
<a-gltf-model id='playerone' class={{#if myplayer playerone}}entitymove{{/if}}  src="#myMixBun"> </a-gltf-model>
```

But since it’s a component, I am at a loss as to how to fix the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this uses Meteor-Blaze templates you need to include the conditionals for DOM element attributes inside quotes/double quotes:

```
<a-gltf-model id='playerone' class="{{#if myplayer playerone}}entitymove{{/if}}"  src="#myMixBun"> </a-gltf-model>
```

Readings:

http://blazejs.org/guide/spacebars.html

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED
This is my original, which doesn’t work.

In main.js:

```
player = "player not active";

Template.hello.helpers(
  counter() {......

// if player one
player = "playerone";
// if player two
player = "playertwo";

return { myplayer: player };
  }
```

In main.html:

```
// This statement works
{{counter.myplayer}}....

<a-gltf-model id='playerone' class="{{#if counter.myplayer playerone}}entitymove{{/if}}"  src="#myMixBun"> </a-gltf-model>

<a-gltf-model id='playertwo' class="{{#if counter.myplayer playertwo}}entitymove{{/if}}"  src="#myMixBun"> </a-gltf-model>
```

I think there are 2 problems with this:

1) spacebars doesn’t seem to like the if statement with a comparison?:

```
{{#if counter.myplayer playertwo}}
```

It only allows true or false if statements?, such as:

```
{{#if counter.player1}}
```

2) My aframe custom component isn’t actually a class, so I can’t put the meteor #if statement inside the  entity.

I changed the code to the following and it now works:

Changed main.js to:

```
playerone ="";
playertwo ="";

// if player one
     playerone = "true";
    playertwo = "";

// if player two
     playerone = "";
    playertwo = "true";
 return { player1: playerone, player2: playertwo};
  }
```

Changed main.html to:

```
// These statements work
{{#if counter.player1}}player1 is true{{/if}}
{{#if counter.player2}}player2 is true{{/if}}....

{{#if counter.player1}}
 <a-gltf-model id='playerone' entitymove   src="#myMixBun" ></a-gltf-model> 
 <a-gltf-model id='playertwo'   src="#myMixBun" ></a-gltf-model> 
 {{/if}}

  {{#if counter.player2}}
 <a-gltf-model id='playerone'  src="#myMixBun" ></a-gltf-model> 
 <a-gltf-model id='playertwo' entitymove   src="#myMixBun" ></a-gltf-model> 
 {{/if}}
```